# Show that $T$ is self adjoint where $Tf(x) := \int k(x,y)f(y)\,dy$ when $k(y,x) = \overline{k(x,y)}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> The operator $Tf(x) := \int k(x,y)f(y)\,dy$ defined on $L^2(\mathbb{R}),$ where $k \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^2))$ is self-adjoint when $k(y,x) = \overline{k(x,y)}$.

We need to show that for any $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that $$\langle Tf(x) , g(x) \rangle = \langle f(x), Tg(x) \rangle$$
We have that
$$\langle Tf(x), g(x) \rangle =  \int k(x,y)f(y)\,dy \int \overline{g(x)}\,dx = \iint k(x,y)f(y)g(x)\, dy\,dx $$
and
$$\langle f(x), Tg(x) \rangle = \int f(x)\,dx \int \overline{k(x,y)g(y)} \,dy = \iint f(x) \overline{k(x,y)} \overline{g(y)} \,dx\,dy.$$
I have no idea how to show that these two integrals are equivalent with the additional condition on the function $k$. I imagine that I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: You are missing the integral over $x$ in both cases.

Comment: Why isn't it $\overline{g(x)}$ in $\langle Tf(x),g(x)\rangle$?

Comment: I edited in between your comments. The answer below formulates it properly though...

Answer (score 1):

Let's write things out using parentheses when necessary.  Since $Tf(x)=\int k(x,y)f(y)\ dy$, we have
$$\langle Tf,g\rangle =\int\left(\int k(x,y)f(y)\ dy\right)\overline{g(x)}\ dx$$
and 
$$\langle f, Tg\rangle=\int f(x)\overline{\left(\int k(x,y)g(y)dy\right)}\ dx.$$
To show that these are equal, start with $\langle Tf,g\rangle$, toy around with the expression, apply Fubini, use $k(x,y)=\overline{k(y,x)}$, toy around some more, and you're done.

Comment: We can look at  $T_a f(x) =1_{|x| < a}\int_{-a}^a k(x,y)f(y)dy $ and say it converges to $T$ when $a \to \infty$